# WebStorm: extract function directly with an arrow

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I try to find a way to extract a function with WebStorm (<kbd>Cmd + Alt + M</kbd>) directly with a fat arrow. But I didn't find a way to do that.

With image:

The start:

```
return _.sum(b.populationCounts) - _.sum(a.populationCounts);
```

The extract method by WebStorm:

```
function getNumber() {
  return _.sum(b.populationCounts) - _.sum(a.populationCounts);
}

return getNumber();
```

What I would like:

```
const getNumber = () =>
  _.sum(b.populationCounts) - _.sum(a.populationCounts);

return getNumber();
```

Is it possible? Someone has already done this?

I know it's possible to convert a function into a variable holding an arrow function but I would like to do it directly by the automatic WebStorm extract.

Thanks for your answer,

Comment: Are you want to convert an arrow function to a regular function? Could you show example before and after?

Comment: please post the code as text rather than as picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are no settings for that; please vote for [WEB-26073](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26073) to be notified on any progress with this feature

Comment: Im also looking forward to see this "extract method setting". Thx for answering